# curl error 56 (failure receiving network data) when run from cron

Tags: bash, curl, cron

I have a bash script that uses curl to retrieve a file. It runs fine when I run it from interactive bash shell but curl fails with exit code 56 (failure in receiving network data) when I run the script with cron. I also get an error message

```
curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961
```

Any ideas?

Crontab entry:

```
57 21 * * * /opt/tltutilities/lss/bin/get_hosts.sh 2>&1 | /bin/mail -s "get_hosts.sh" me@addr.edu
```

Bash script:

```
#!  /bin/bash
BASEDIR=/opt/tltutilities/lss
cd $BASEDIR/bin
curl -v -o /opt/tltutilities/lss/tmp/etc_hosts https://remote_host.edu/pub/hosts/hosts
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then
  errmsg="curl: can't get hosts file: `grep \"^$rc \" curl_error_codes.txt`"
  echo $errmsg
  echo "$errmsg" | /bin/mail -s "get_hosts.sh failed with curl error $rc" me@addr.edu
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to define/export `https_proxy` environment variable, which is not set in cron-supplied environment.

Answer (score 0):

The server from where file is fetched responds to mTLS/https(trusted) connections which cron doesn't seem to provide.

Comment: And given this, how you would solve it?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32441644)